The task in the Airflow DAG is stuck in the "up_for_reschedule" state, even though the dependent tasks have already been completed
Here is config code

with DAG(
    dag_id=f"Dummy-test",
    description="Dummy_test",
    schedule_interval="0 4 * * *",
    default_args=default_args,
    start_date=datetime(2024, 2, 1, tzinfo=pendulum.timezone(LOCAL_TZ)),
    max_active_runs=1,
    catchup=False,
    on_failure_callback=lambda context: pd_operation.trigger_incident(context=context),
) as dag:

Here is the code for the dependency task
   T_wait_test_END = TaskSensor(
        task_id="wait_test_END",
        external_dag_id="Dummy-test",
        timeout=86400,
        allowed_states=["success"],
        external_task_id="test_END",
    )

I'm pretty sure test_END is already in a successful state because I manually set it to success.
But when I start the dag it's still stuck in the up_for_reschedule state even if I clear its state and start again.
Does this have anything to do with the schedule_interval of the DAG?

There is no TaskSensor class  in Airflow. Either it's a custom class you develop or something that comes from external package thus it's impossible to answer as you didn't share the source code of this class.
